# Novel about girl growing up in a mirror universe, searching for surface world

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, parallel-universe

I read this book on my Amazon Kindle.

There was a girl whose father disappeared and she went on to later volunteer/work for some sort of research company. She had a dream where she saw a man shoot her neighbor and he turned out to also work at this company with an older man who is the boss.

They tell her it is possible to travel through mirrors but the timelines are the same until the moment you pass through. They at first play around with it, make some fake money using the mirrors, mess around with people etc. She goes to her mirror high school prom where in that universe she is popular.

Her dad comes back briefly but is "crazy" and said he had been looking for her for a long time. He either dies or gets taken away.

The girl does some mirror exploring on her own and figures out that the boss is trying to find the "surface world." The infinite worlds degenerate the further you get away from the surface because the reflection is not as clear. The boss tries to stick her in a copy world by taking her there and breaking the mirror she came through. You can only use the mirror you came in through or else you are going to a copy further down.

Anyway, the boss steals the "key to the surface" and takes off through mirrors. They track him without getting lost because he used the pattern of her DNA to make a maze of mirrors and they figured it out. They do get lost and have to back track a bit but they eventually find him with his arms cut off because he was trying to fit through the mirror. It was a mirror from the benches you see at the shoe store. She had crawled through it as a child and not realized. Her whole life she had been in a copy world and didn't know it.

She manages to get through the small mirror and find out the Dad that had come back was her actual dad that figured out where she went. And the boy who she had been working with was real and waiting for her on the surface world as he could see through his copy's eyes when he slept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Broken Symmetry* (2013) by Dan Rix?

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0989206440):

> **Eleven months after the father of sixteen-year-old Blaire Adams vanished without a trace, he's found wandering outside The Scripps Research Institute vomiting blood and speaking gibberish**, his sole possession a worn leather diary filled with an unrecognizable language. He has a message for her.
>
> As he dies in her arms, he claims he never vanished. She vanished.
>
> **In a nearby military quarantine zone, scientists are being called in from around the world to sequence a previously unknown strain of DNA.** Scientists...and soldiers.
>
> When her father’s autopsy reveals a rare chromosomal disorder—a disorder, it turns out, she inherited—Blaire begins to suspect her father’s last words weren’t induced by amnesia. **Like her dad, she has an additional set of instructions in her genes—instructions for what, doctors can’t say.** Only one thing is certain: it’s what killed him...and it will kill her too.
>
> But now she’s haunted by prophetic nightmares of the Yellowjacket—a young murderer, eyes the black of charcoal, who lures his victims to suicide without ever paying them a visit. The only clue she has to his handiwork is a lingering feeling of déjà vu. **That, and the nagging suspicion that all she knows is a mirage.** She is certain of two things—though it may mean confiding in the wrong side of good and evil, he has the answers she needs.
>
> And he is recruiting her.

The [Goodreads blurb](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18334136-broken-symmetry) has her trapped:

> When she narrowly escapes a military quarantine zone with the San Diego Police Department hot on her heels **only to discover her escape mirror littering the floor in shards, her worst fear is realized. Now, trapped in a broken reflection, she must flee through a mind-bending maze of mirrors**, going deeper into the nightmare as she struggles to grasp a betrayal, uncover the chilling truth about her ability, and somehow find a way out of a dead-end universe that “never happened.”
>
> **Somehow, she must find a way home.**

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction book father mirror universe company surface site:goodreads.com/book`.